# Getting camera buffer using Qt with c++ and QML

Tags: ubuntu-touch, c++, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

I am new in Ubuntu touch apps development.

my question is : is there a method to get a buffer or images from phone camera using C++. after that, i must process these images pixel per pixel and past the result to QML.

thnx